# How to join two overlapped images?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I need to join two images in Matlab. The two binary images are left and right images with some overlapping in between and I need to merge them in Matlab to make a single image (like a panorama except the images are just 2D line drawings and there is no noise, e.g. the overlapped regions are perfectly identical).

Therefore if I would like to find the common columns from both images and then create a new image such as

```
new_image = [left_image(excluding-the-common-columns) right_image]
```

and then just plot it.

I tried to use the 'intersect' method, but all I have achieved so far is finding the common elements and not common columns.

How can I find the common columns in such images?

Comment: I don't really have a code atm as I'm stuck at finding the intersect columns.

Comment: *So far I have multiple ways to find common columns using 'intersect'*. Please elaborate.

Comment: This is not a "code not working" problem and therefore should be closed. It is ontopic as the accepted solution kind of proves. It should be reopened.

Comment: Sorry, meant "should not be closed".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ismember()` to find rows common to two arrays. Just transpose your matrix to get the same functionality for columns. Like so:

```
im = imread('forest.tif');
left = im(:, 1:300);
right = im(:, 200:end);
a = ismember(left', right', 'rows');
first_common_index = find(a, 1);
joined = [left(:, 1:first_common_index), right];
```

Then doing

```
figure
subplot(2,2,1);
imshow(left, []);
title('Left')

subplot(2,2,2);
imshow(right, []);
title('Right')

subplot(2,2,[3,4]);
imshow(joined, []);
title('Joined')
```

gives

[image]

Comment: Thnx. Really appreciated.
Precisely what I needed to do.

Comment: Just a warning to others: this only works if the two images have columns that are exactly equal. For real images this should not very often be the case although implementing some kind of similarity criterion should not be that difficult. So this answer solved the problem of the OP but may not solve other similar problems. :)

Comment: @Trilarion Definitely true! For images that do agree perfectly in some part at least it's not too hard, but for anything that does not agree 100% in at least part of the image it gets a lot more difficult